# Concavity and Inflection of Natural Log

Tags: calculus

I am struggling a little to figure out the best way to find the concavity and inflection points of the below function (and other similar functions)

$f(x)=-\ln(5x^2 + 6)$

First I get $f'(x)=\frac{-10}{5x^2+6}$

Then $f''(x)=\frac{10(5x^2+6)}{(5x^2+6)^2}$

From here I get a little lost on how to find the interval for $f''(x)$ in order to find where $f''(x)$ is concave up or down and the inflection points. I have been setting it to zero but not been able to solve.

I am wondering if someone can help guide me through the best way to solve these types of problems? Or if you have a good recommendation on study material?

Comment: I think that $f'(x)$ is not correct and then the same for $f''(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got $$f''(x)=\frac{10 \left(5 x^2-6\right)}{\left(5 x^2+6\right)^2}$$
and with $$f''(x)=0$$ you will get the inflection points $$x_w$$.(If $$f'''(x_w)\neq 0$$